# Integration test with rspec with factory girl fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have been testing three models in my ruby on rails project, using rspec with factory girl.
I have 3 files in the folder: spec/models. Two from them contain one test and the third contains 12 tests. Each test that I start separately follows to the green dot. But if I run the whole folder, only the file with 12 tests passes and the two others fail with the error message:

```
Failure/Error: @attr = attributes_for(:transaction) 
ArgumentError: 
   Factory not registered: transaction
```

and similar for other tests.
If I move two of the failed files to a separate folder and start this new folder - one test passes and other fails. But if I turn off Factory girl from this two files - both pass.
This is how some of my failed tests look like:

```
describe Chart do
  before(:each) do
    Chart.delete_all
    @attr = attributes_for(:chart)
  end

  it "should create a new instance of chart given valid attributes" do
    Chart.create!(@attr)
  end
end

describe Transaction do
  before(:each) do
    Transaction.delete_all 
    @attr = attributes_for(:transaction)
  end

  it "should create a new instance of transaction given valid attributes" do
    Transaction.create!(@attr)
  end
end
```

Factory definition:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
FactoryGirl.factories.clear
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :transaction do |u|
    u.code 54321
    u.glcode 5
    u.amount 100.0
    u.date {Date.today}
  end 
end
```

It looks than something somewhere is not cleaned but what and when?
Adding in spec_helper the code:

```
config.before(:suite) do 
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation 
end 

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end 

config.after(:each) do 
  DatabaseCleaner.clean 
end
```

nothing changes.

Would appreciate it if anyone could help. Thanks.

Comment: - Can you show the definition of the `:transaction` factory?
- And put your code example in proper blocks so its easier to read?
- Why don't you use `FactoryGirl.create(:transaction)` ?  That way has always worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined your transaction factory? If not, define it in your **spec/factories.rb** file:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :transaction do
    # ...
  end
end
```

If you have, check that you've included `FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` in your test suite:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

Otherwise you'll need to prefix all `factory_girl` methods with `FactoryGirl`. E.g. `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:transaction)`.

**Update:**

Since you've defined your transaction factory, I would check your configuration. Which file does your factory reside in? Are you positive you've included the syntax methods in your configuration (check spelling)? What happens when you prefix the method with `FactoryGirl`? I.e. `FactoryGirl.attributes(:transaction)`

Comment: Yes, I have this line in my spec_helper.rb file. My factory definition looks like   :FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :transaction do |u|
      u.code 54321
      u.glcode 5
      u.amount 100.0
      u.date {Date.today}
    
    #  initialize_with { new(attributes) }
  end 

end

Comment: You should include this factory in your question; it will be useful for other users when reviewing your question.

Comment: Done: factory definition included in question

Comment: I have found the reason of such error but don't know how to fix it: each test requires two own files: from models and from factories. For some reason rails sees only last files and only one test(file) passes from folder. By other words it looks that when I start test folder rails loads all required files from each file from folder before it starts run the first test, but when running tests rails sees only required files for the last test and only this test passes.

Comment: Are you requiring `spec_helper` in each of your spec files?

Comment: Yes, in each file: require 'spec_helper'
require Rails.root.join('app', 'models', 'transaction.rb')
require Rails.root.join('spec', 'factories', 'transactions.rb') , where two last requirements specific for each file.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this error line: 
    FactoryGirl.factories.clear 
in factory definition. But this line was added to fix previous error:          (FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError).
And that line really fixed that error but only for separate test. So to fix original error I have to:
1. Remove lines
    FactoryGirl.factories.clear from factory definition
2. Wrap Factory definition by
    if !FactoryGirl.factories.registered?(:transaction)
    end
block.
This is completely fixed declared error but may be better to understand the reason why each factory calling twice and remove the reason.